# JAVA - How to populate a JList with the contents of ResultSet after querying a MS Access DB

Tags: java, sql, database, arrays, jlist

```
private void populateJlist(){
    try
    {
        Connection connection = newConnection.createConnection();
        Statement newStat = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet res = newStat.executeQuery("SELECT AccName FROM AccList");

                String data = "";
        while (res.next()){
            data += res.getString("AccName") + " ";
        }
        String acclist[] = data.split(" ");
        AccountList = new JList(acclist);
        newStat.close();
        connection.close();

    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        System.err.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

WHAT IS SHOULD DO - The method will query the DB  AccName column from AccList Table and get all account names and insert them onto a Jlist

WHAT I NEED HELP WITH - I need help implementing a Jlist which will be filled with fields from a DB column.

I tried by searching online for help and the nearest to a solution was what I manage to do above.

I learnt that there are 2 possible ways

Resultset -> Array -> Jlist
Resultset -> Vector -> Jlist

however I dont know how to do those conversions either. I would say I am a new beginner in JAVA. Any detailed help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, using either an array or a vector would be cleaner and easier than your split solution.  Personally, I would suggest the Vector.  Basically, you want to create an empty vector, iterate over the result set adding each value to the vector via the `Vector.add(Object o)` method, then create the jlist outside the loop with the vector. Something like this (warning: untested)

```
Vector<String> temp = new Vector<String>();
while (res.next()) {
    temp.add(res.getString("AccName"));
}
Jlist acctList = new Jlist(temp);
```

Comment: I tried it out!; 

It worked like a charm, I understand know vectors work too, I was trying a similar method before with an array, however that didn't go quite well either. 

I really appreciate your help, 

Thanks